# Can't remove items from ComboBox without crashing

Tags: c#, combobox, crash

In my application I'd like to give the user the option to delete items from a `ComboBox` control by the press of the `Del` button. I have managed to effectively do the first part, but what I can't seem to accomplish is actually delete an item (especially when it's the last one remaining) from the control without the whole application crashing. Why is that? Here's my code. It always throws an **ArgumentOutOfRange** exception when the last item is removed and contains the message **InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.**

```
private void cboSource_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    deleteItem(cboSource, e);
}

private void cboTarget_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    deleteItem(cboTarget, e);
}

private void deleteItem(ComboBox comboBox, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Remove(comboBox.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

I have two ComboBoxes and a function to delete the items, but I guess it won't be much of a problem now, right?

EDIT: The crash usually happens when no items are left and the control loses focus.

Comment: Just some suggestion: If no item is selected in the combobox, pressing Del will cause an invocation of comboBox.Items.Remove(**null**). Is that perhaps your issue?

Comment: why are you calling DeleteItem 2 times for KeyUp and KeyDown?  this can be a problem - you try to delete item twice.

Comment: @realnero, where do you see KeyUp?

Comment: Is there any other code that works with combobox items that is fired after you delete the item? Have you checked the stacktrace to see what is throwing the error?

Comment: For me it looks like there were only 1 item in combobox and you tried to delete it twice...

Comment: MSDN documentation of **comboBox.Items.Remove** is pretty ambiguous. Trying to delete an item twice should not result in an exception, it says (it precisely says "*No exception is thrown if the specified item is not found.*"). Now, it doesn't say anything about what happens when you pass a **null** argument... hmm...

Comment: @realnero the 2 deleteItem methods in this code are getting 2 different comboBoxes as parameter

Comment: I just tested this code in winforms and it works perfect here. How do u feed the items to the comboboxes ?

Comment: The items are being fed to the comboboxes using folder browser dialogs. But that process works just fine. Oh, and one thing I noticed, the application crashes when the combobox I'm deleting items from is left with no items and the control loses focus. That's interesting, if I don't click away the application is still functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fix I figured out by messing with the code a bit. I'm not entirely sure as to why it works, but it works. This by no means is a viable solution for me, though, as it still is a "work around", in the sense that I'm working around the problem and am not actually solving it. Until someone finds a better way, I guess I will stick to this. Here is the code:

```
private void deleteItem(ComboBox comboBox, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if (comboBox.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Clear();

            return;
        }

        comboBox.Items.Remove(comboBox.SelectedItem);

        e.Handled = true; // I do not think this really contributes anything in this case.
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, guess I will, but, if you or anyone else comes with a better solution, you're very welcome to post. :) There's still time, though, before the website allows me to accept my own question (23 hours remaining).

Comment: There is something going on in your code... Look carefully at the stack trace of your original exception, that should give you a clear picture of how and probably why the exception was thrown. The meaning of "Better solution" can only be given in the context of probable cause of your problem...

Comment: I have the same problem, but the above solution does not help. The crash always happens if you remove the last item (or clear all items) within a Key handler, when a key is pressed while in the DropDown state. I think it is a bug in the control itself, as it causes the 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll. I checked all handlers: KeyPress, KeyDown, KeyUp - all present the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by closing the drop-down list, before remove the last element.

```
private void cmbUserLogin_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && cmbUserLogin.DroppedDown)
    {
        if (cmbUserLogin.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            int currentItem = cmbUserLogin.SelectedIndex;
            if (currentItem >= 0)
            {
                // todo

                if (cmbUserLogin.Items.Count == 1)
                    cmbUserLogin.DroppedDown = false;
                cmbUserLogin.Items.RemoveAt(currentItem);
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add a default item to the combox which will never be deleted and likely to the first item or you can reinitialize an empty item list to avoid crash.

Comment: Isn't there a way for it to just work without any one of these workarounds? It's not that what you're proposing is bad, I'm just wondering if there is a way to actually do it.

Comment: AFAIK, without a default item it wont be possible. I am not completely certain if other ways are around or not.

Comment: Default item won't help in this case, crash happens because item doesn't exist with specified index.

Comment: A default empty item (last in the list) was a solution that actually helped me. We are talking about a workaround for a bug in the control itself, not a general method of handling lists. This was the only viable solution from all proposed above, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small sample in `WPF` with your code and it doesn't crash. From what I see you are not using the `WPF`. Still, to make you feel better - your code should be work out of the box. But there are a couple of things that I see from your post:

1.The error that you are getting `ArgumentOutOfRange` happens when you try to manipulate an item in the list using the index that cannot get you that item. So  if there are 3 items in the list and you try to access list.Items[3], you'll get that error.

2.`InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'` tells me that you are not only accessing the index that doesn't exist, but you are accessing the element with index zero, assuming that the combo box list has at least one element in it. So what's happening is that you are somehow attempting to delete the last item in the combo box, when the combo box is already empty. Hence the error. 
To solve that:

```
 //before delete, check if combo box has items
    if(comobBox.Items.Count > 0)      
    {
         comboBox.Items.Remove(comboBox.SelectedItem);
         //edit: this might help with that last crash (from comments)
         if(comboBox.Items.Count == 0)
             comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

That's not a bad practice to check especially if there are multiple entry points to the same code, not even mentioning multi-threaded possibilities..
Also, it might not be a bad idea to check whether the selected item is not null as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do anything to help me. Although it would make sense if it worked. I have noticed that when the crash occurs, it is after I click AWAY from the combobox. If I delete the last item and leave the focus on the control, I can still type.

Comment: ah, so that might mean that you have deleted the selected item but didn't clear it, let me post a hypothetical update to my answer..

Comment: Your edit still crashes after clicking away. Now that's really peculiar as I can follow your logic and it seems fine to me.